# TFIDF calculation in Lucene while restricting time range

Tags: lucene, tf-idf

I've got a lots of documents in different time. 
Now I need to calculate the tfidf for documents in one period of time.
The following is what i am going to do, for example:

I have one million text documents for one year, I'll take the documents in one month as a corpus.
I want to calculate the tfidf for each month, i.e., calculating the term frequency in one month, and multiply the inverse document frequency **in remaining month**.

The data (text, time etc.) is indexed using **lucene**, I just wondered whether lucene could facilitate the calculation of such a scenario
I know Lucene can help me get the term frequency and document frequency, but is there any API for restricting the **time range** for calculation?

Much Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got a solution for this using Lucene.Net 3.0.3 and payloads. I'm not sure if this is the best way to accomplish this using the java-version which currently is some way ahead of the .net port.

It works by assigning a payload, a custom byte-array, to terms that should be custom scored, and a custom Similarity that overrides ScorePayload to parse the byte-array to do custom filtering. (this would require a query that calls this method, like the PayloadTermQuery).

This highly contrived example code will score the term based on (id % 3). (Multiples of three are scored zero). You could use this combined with a PositiveScoresOnlyCollector to ignore matches that receives a zero score.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Lucene.Net.Analysis;
using Lucene.Net.Analysis.Tokenattributes;
using Lucene.Net.Documents;
using Lucene.Net.Index;
using Lucene.Net.Search;
using Lucene.Net.Search.Payloads;
using Lucene.Net.Store;

public static class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var directory = new RAMDirectory();

        // Initialization; create 50 documents with payload
        var writer = new IndexWriter(directory, new KeywordAnalyzer(), true, IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED);
        for (var i = 0; i < 50; ++i) {
            AddDocument(writer, i, "lorem ipsum etc blah blah");
        }
        writer.Commit();

        var searcher = new IndexSearcher(directory, readOnly: true);
        searcher.Similarity = new ShazaamPayloadSimilarity();

        // The term we'll be looking for. This should match all documents.
        var term = new Term("Data", "lorem");
        var query = new PayloadTermQuery(term, new MaxPayloadFunction());
        var topDocs = searcher.Search(query, 40);

        // This is a bad example of a FieldCache usage.
        var iValues = FieldCache_Fields.DEFAULT.GetStrings(searcher.IndexReader, "Id");
        foreach (var scoreDoc in topDocs.ScoreDocs) {
            Console.WriteLine("Score: {0:0.0000}  i={1}", scoreDoc.Score, iValues[scoreDoc.Doc]);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void AddDocument(IndexWriter writer, Int32 id, String data) {
        var payload = BitConverter.GetBytes(id);
        var analyzer = new ShazaamPayloadAnalyzer(payload);
        var textReader = new StringReader(data);

        var document = new Document();
        document.Add(new Field("Id", id.ToString(), Field.Store.NO, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
        document.Add(new Field("Data", analyzer.TokenStream(null, textReader)));

        writer.AddDocument(document);
    }
}

public class ShazaamPayloadAnalyzer : Analyzer {
    private readonly Byte[] _value;

    public ShazaamPayloadAnalyzer(Byte[] value) {
        _value = value;
    }

    public override TokenStream TokenStream(String fieldName, TextReader reader) {
        TokenStream result = new WhitespaceTokenizer(reader);
        result = new ShazaamPayloadFilter(result, _value);
        return result;
    }
}

public class ShazaamPayloadFilter : TokenFilter {
    private readonly byte[] _payload;
    private readonly IPayloadAttribute _payloadAttr;

    public ShazaamPayloadFilter(TokenStream input, Byte[] payload)
        : base(input) {
        _payload = payload;
        _payloadAttr = AddAttribute<IPayloadAttribute>();
    }

    public override Boolean IncrementToken() {
        if (input.IncrementToken()) {
            _payloadAttr.Payload = new Payload(_payload);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}

public class ShazaamPayloadSimilarity : DefaultSimilarity {
    public override Single ScorePayload(Int32 docId, String fieldName, Int32 start, Int32 end, Byte[] payload, Int32 offset, Int32 length) {
        var originalValue = BitConverter.ToInt32(payload, startIndex: 0);

        // Advanced logic ahead!
        return (originalValue % 3);
    }
}
```